# Fetching an array from server side for use with JS later?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a webpage that will contact the server, get an array of integers, and then somehow make that array available to a javascript function:

```
function doSomething(var arrayFromServer) {

     for (var i=0; i<arrayFromServer.length; i++) {
              var element = arrayFromServer[i];
              /* do something with each element... */
     }
}
```

How is this done, or is there an easier way to accomplish the same thing? LAMPPP is available, but I'm not sure how to use the stack most effectively here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `JSON` for this. The server can send the object stringified into JSON and then you can decode it client side.

```
json_str = "[1,2,3]"; // string sent from server
arr = JSON.parse(json_str); // returns the original object which was encoded.
```

Depending on the server side language, there various ways to encode an object in JSON.